# Passar valor de um select por javascript

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde, sou novo no desenvolvimento e estou tentando criar um formulário que colete determinadas informações e gere um arquivo .xls. para evitar erros do preenchimento inseri select com todas as opções possíveis porem precisava otimizar a busca e pesquisando vi a possibilidade de usar jquerry que permitiam digitar e facilitar a busca porem ao usar o script meu form não retorna o valor selecionado na select.

exeplo do html - esta no meu index.html:

```
<select id="fornecedor" class="form-control" placeholder="Selecione o fornecedor"></select>
```

Script que utilizo para permitir pesquisar valores dentro da select

```
<script>$('#fornecedor').editableSelect();</script>
```

exemplo de como estou preenchendo o select - combo.js:

```
var comboForn = document.getElementById("fornecedor");
var opt0fn  = document.createElement("option"); opt0fn.value = "0"; opt0fn.text = "Selecione o fornecedor",comboForn.add(opt0fn, comboForn.options[0]);
var opt1fn = document.createElement("option");opt1fn.value = "0";opt1fn.text = "0 - INDEFINIDO",comboForn.add(opt1fn, comboForn.options[1]);
var opt2fn = document.createElement("option");opt2fn.value = "100034";opt2fn.text = "100034 - LOJAS AMERICANAS S.A.",comboForn.add(opt2fn, comboForn.options[2]);
```

form - book-form.js onde monto meu arquivo para gerar posteriormente o .xls

```
const bookForm = (function($){
    var BOOK_SOLIC = $('#solicitante');
    var BOOK_FIL = $('#filial');
    var BOOK_TIP = $("#tipo");
    var BOOK_PLANO = $("#plano");
    var BOOK_CENT = $("#centro");
    var BOOK_FOR = $("#fornecedor");
    var BOOK_VLRT = $("#valor_total");
    var BOOK_VLRP = $("#valor_parcela");
    var BOOK_QT = $("#quantidade")
    var BOOK_DESC = $("#descricao");
    var BOOK_APR = $("#aprovacao");

    const BOOK_UPDATE_BUTTON = $("#updateButton");

    function clear() {
        setData();
        BOOK_SOLIC.focus();
    }

    function hasErrors() {
        return BOOK_SOLIC.val() === null || BOOK_SOLIC.val() === '';
    }

    function getData() {
        return {
            solicitante: BOOK_SOLIC.val(),
            filial: BOOK_FIL.val(),
            tipo: BOOK_TIP.val(),
            plano: BOOK_PLANO.val(),
            centro: BOOK_CENT.val(),
            fornecedor: BOOK_FOR.val(),
            valor_total: BOOK_VLRT.val(),
            valor_parcela: BOOK_VLRP.val(),
            quantidade: BOOK_QT.val(),
            descricao: BOOK_DESC.val(),
            aprovacao: BOOK_APR.val(),
        };
    }

    function setData(solicitante='', option='', tipo='', plano='', centro='', fornecedor='', valor_total='',  valor_parcela='', quantidade='', descricao='', aprovacao='') {
        BOOK_SOLIC.val(solicitante);
        BOOK_FIL.val(filial);
        BOOK_TIP.val(tipo);
        BOOK_PLANO.val(plano);
        BOOK_CENT.val(centro);
        BOOK_FOR.val(fornecedor);
        BOOK_VLRT.val(valor_total);
        BOOK_VLRP.val(valor_parcela);
        BOOK_QT.val(quantidade);
        BOOK_DESC.val(descricao);
        BOOK_APR.val(aprovacao);
    }

    function setSubmitButtonText(str) {
        BOOK_UPDATE_BUTTON.text(str);
    }

    function getSubmitButtonText() {
        return BOOK_UPDATE_BUTTON.text();
    }

    return {
        clear: clear,
        hasErrors: hasErrors,
        getData: getData,
        setData: setData,
        setSubmitButtonText: setSubmitButtonText,
        getSubmitButtonText: getSubmitButtonText,
    };
})(jQuery);
```

desculpem se não tiver no padrão de perguntas e desde já agradeço pela ajuda. abs.

Answer (score -1):

como é um select experimenta esse modelo aqui:

```
var se_pais = $("#comboboxpais option:selected").val();
```

Comment: Ao tentar este método não trouxe o valor selecionado para a tabela, mais não deu erro quando tento inserir o valor como nos outros que tentei, creio que falte apenas uma pequena coisa no código que ainda não consegui identificar

Comment: Melhora sua pergunta. Dá uma olhada como fazer isso. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/conduct